# Script for multiple erlang applications multiple computers and some other questions

Tags: bash, erlang, config, distributed, rebar3

I have two Erlang applications, for example, `app1` and `app2`. I want to run them on three nodes when each node has its own config file.
Also, I need to run `app1` before `app2`.
`app1` must be running on every node. `app2` is the same program for all nodes, but only one node runs it at the same time; the other nodes waits for the case of the current node will fail.

Example of running:

node 1:

```
erl -sname cp1 config cp1
application:start(app1).
application:start(app2).
```

node 2:

```
erl -sname cp2 config cp2
application:start(app1).
application:start(app2).
```

node 3:

```
erl -sname cp3 config cp3
application:start(app1).
application:start(app2).
```

All nodes need to start together because of the sync time (I set this parameter to 10000) in the config file and the same for `app2`.
To check that my program works as I want, I do this by myself, that's easy: I have control on the timing, I open a terminator with 3 terminals, do a copy-paste to commands and everything is ok.

My questions are:
I have 3 computers. I need one node for one computer. How to write a script for each computer that does it automatically?
Can I insert Erlang commands to bash script? What the best way to do this?
How can I deal with the problem of sync? Can I set sync time to infinity?

cp1 code: (same for the others, just with changes in sync mandatory)

```
[{kernel,
  [{distributed, [{app2, 2000, [{cp1@dev1, cp2@dev1, cp3@dev1}]}
    ]},
   {sync_nodes_mandatory, [cp2@dev1, cp3@dev1]},
   {sync_nodes_timeout, 10000}
  ]
 }
].
```

app2.app code:

```
{application, app2,
 [{description, "An OTP application"},
  {vsn, "0.1.0"},
  {registered, []},
  {mod, {app2_app, []}},
  {applications,
   [kernel,
    stdlib,
    app1
   ]},
  {env,[]},
  {modules, []},

  {licenses, ["Apache 2.0"]},
  {links, []}
 ]}.
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have 3 computers, I need 1 node for 1 computer. How to write a
> script for each computer that does it automatically?

I'd recommend using a tool to generate a release, such as [rebar3](https://www.rebar3.org/docs/releases), the release includes a boot script that starts the node with the config files.
I'd also recommend activating the [-heart flag](http://erlang.org/doc/man/heart.html) in your case, or install the release as a `systemd` service.

> Can I insert erlang commands to bash script? What the best way to do
> this?

You can use [escript](https://erlang.org/doc/man/escript.html) to handle this, you can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62009886/erlang-and-bash-scripting-escript/62030721#62030721) for a example on how to do that (TL;DR: You can, but it starts a new node).

> How can I deal with the problem of sync? Can I set sync time to
> infinity?

From [distributed applications](https://erlang.org/doc/design_principles/distributed_applications.html), yes, you can set the sync time to `infinity`.